# Looking for a book whose title roughly translates to Way to Oregon

Tags: identification-request

I am looking for a book whose title roughly translates to "Way to Oregon". The author was a person of color, probably an African-American.

The story is about a group who were involved in trade when Europeans first arrived in America. There was frequent killing of bison and native Americans to clear land for new settlements.

The book was published at least before 1965. It was a thick hardcover book. The writer shared his first-hand experience of travelling from the east coast to the west coast. At that time, slavery was still in place in some of the states but written off in some states on the east coast.

The book was a Bengali version translated from English. The Bengali title was "Oregon er Pothe". I do not remember the genre, though.

Comment: The title that translates roughly to "Way to Oregon" is likely to be "Oregon Trail." Unfortunately, because the [Oregon Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oregon_Trail) is the name of a very famous route from the east-central part of the United States westward almost to the Pacific coast, there are many books with "Oregon Trail" in the title.

Comment: Do you have more information about this book? Do you remember when you read it? Was it a nonfiction book, a novel, or a collection of short stories? Was the person of color Native American, African American, or some other ethnicity? Were the people in the book also people of color?

Comment: Do you know the exact title of the Bengali translation?

Comment: The author is probably an African-American. It is a novel.

Comment: What is the Bengali title? Exactly? In Bengali?

Comment: "Oregon er Pothe"

Comment: That's definitely *Oregon Trail*. As @shoover said in the comment above, there are too many books with that title. If you have more details about the incidents in the book (the more specific the better), and if you tell us when you read it / when it was published / translated ... whatever you can remember, it would help narrow it down. Please edit your question with those details, don't add them in comments. Thanks!

Comment: The book was published at least before 1965. It was a thick hardcover book. The writer shared his first-hand experience of travelling from the east coast to the west coast. That time slavery was still in place in some of the states but written off in some states on the east coast

Comment: Well, here's a Google Books search, not sure how to make it try "Oregon Trail", instead of anything with the two words, but it's a start? https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=intitle:Oregon+intitle:Trail&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_min:Jan+1_2+1900,cd_max:Dec+31_2+1965&num=10